# Values received from parsing remote HTML file using simple HTML DOM Parser are not getting stored into mysql database

Tags: mysql, parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to store some parsed data into mysql database. My code is given below:

```
<?php
include('mysql_connection.php');
include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

$site = "www.xyz.com/19326072316";
$html = file_get_html($site);
foreach($html->find('body') as $body)
{
    foreach($body->find('a.url') as $e)
    {
        $title = $e->plaintext;
        echo '<b>Title: </b>' . $title . '<br>';
    }
    foreach($body->find('a.category') as $cat)
    {
        $category = $cat->plaintext;
        echo '<b>Category: </b>' . $category . '<br>';
    }
    preg_match('/(\w+)\.xyz\.com\/.+/', $site, $matches);
    $city = $matches[1];
    echo '<b>City: </b>' . $matches[1] . '<br>';

    foreach($body->find('div.month') as $month){
        $month = $month->plaintext;
        echo '<b>Start and end month: </b>' . $month . '<br>';
    }
    foreach($body->find('div.date') as $date){
        $date = $date->plaintext;
        preg_match('/([0-9]{1,2})/', $date, $match_date);
        $date = $match_date[0];
        echo '<b>Start and end date: </b>' . $date . '<br>';
    }
    foreach($body->find('li.new_WatchIcon') as $time){
        $time = $time->plaintext;
        echo '<b>Time: </b>' . $time . '<br>';
    }
    foreach($body->find('li#new_locationIconIE7 div') as $address){
        $address = $address->plaintext;
        echo '<b>Address: </b>' . $address . '<br>';
    }
    foreach($body->find('span.description') as $description){
        $description = $description->innertext;
        echo '<b>description: </b>' . $description . '<br>';
    }

    $query = ("INSERT INTO articles (event_name, date_added, start_date, start_month, end_date, end_month, year, city, state, full_address, time, description, contact) VALUES('$title', now(), '$date', '$month', '$date', '$month', '2014', '$city', 'Karnatka', '$address', '$time', '$description', 'NULL')") or die(mysql_error());

    $run_query = mysqli_query($query, $connection); 
}
?>
```

When I was using `mysql_query`, nothing was happening but when I used `mysqli_query` then I got following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
```

I know this question is already asked many times, but I tried most of the ways to solve this issue, but nothing worked for me!

Comment: You are not checking the results of your call to mysqli_query.  Also please note that mysql_query and mysqli_query have nothing to do with each other.  They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong order of the parameters of mysqli_query(). Instead of your

```
$run_query = mysqli_query($query, $connection);
```

it should be

```
$run_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

It would be a great enhancement, if you would use a prepared statement with placeholders for your `INSERT` query:

```
// Prepare the statement before your outer foreach loop:
$query = "INSERT INTO articles (event_name, date_added, start_date, start_month, end_date, end_month, year, city, state, full_address, time, description, contact) 
             VALUES (?, now(), ?, ?, ?, ?, '2014', ?, 'Karnatka', ?, ?, ?, NULL)";
// instead of mysqli_query use in the loop
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query) {
    // your parameters are all of string type and you have 9
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
        $stmt, 
        'sssssssss', 
        $title, $date, $month, $date, $month, $city, $address, $description);

    foreach($html->find('body') as $body) {
        // Please take care, that you only can assign values to those variables

        // and execute the insert at the end of your loop
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
```

Remarks:
I thought the last parameter of your query would be the special value `NULL` and not the string `'NULL'`.

Comment: Now, I'm getting Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference. Should all variables to be declared at two places? One in $query and other one in mysqli_stmt_bind_param?

Comment: @user2902000 Sorry, I got it wrong. You've got to prepare the statement out of your loop, even bind those variables before the loop. Use only assignment of values in the loop.

Comment: Now, this is my code:

$query = ("INSERT INTO articles VALUES('$title', now(), '$date1',... NULL)");
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query))
{
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($connection, $title, ...);
}
foreach($html->find('body') as $body)
{
 foreach($body->find('a.url') as $e){
        {...}
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

But, still I'm getting same error.